# Images display vertically instead of horizontally in FF & Chrome

Tags: image, firefox, css-float, vertical-alignment, alignment

I hope someone can help me! My images are displaying vertically instead of horizontally in FF and Chrome, but displays perfectly (horizontally) in IE. I know html somewhat, and very little about css properties, so I'm having a devil of a time trying to sort this problem out. After months of searching forums, I've come to the conclusion that the problem I'm having has something to do with either "width" properties, a jquery accordion menu I added to the website, or both. The problem started after I inserted the html and css for the accordion menu. You can view an example here (with FF or Chrome browser): [Spring Creek Rustic Outfitters](http://stores.homestead.com/springcreekrusticoutfitters/-strse-214/Rustic-Natural-Cedar-Arched/Detail.bok)

HTML portion of code in question:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <ss:if test="$product.defaultImage"> 
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="imgtable" rules="none">
            <tr>
                <td valign="middle" align="center" width="100%" height="100%" id="divMediumContainer">
                    <ss:set name="item" value="$product.defaultImage"/>

                    <ss:if test="$item.hasMediumSize()">
                            <ss:set name="urlMedium" value="$item.medium"/>
                    <ss:else/>
                            <ss:set name="urlMedium" value="$item.small"/>
                    </ss:if>

                    <ss:image id="imgMedium" source="$urlMedium" title="$item.title" class="click"/>         
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br />

        <ss:foreach item="productMedia" within="$product.images">
            <ss:if test="$counter.totalRows > 1">
                <ss:set name="item" value="$productMedia.storeMediaItem"/>
                <ss:if test="$item.hasSmallSize()">
                    <div style="padding:2px 2px 2px 2px"><div id="$system.concat('divSmallImage_', $counter.currentRow)" class="imagesmallcontainer">
                        <ss:image id="$system.concat('imgSmall_', $counter.currentRow)" source="$item.getImage('small')" calcoffset="65"/>
                    </div></div>
                    <ss:if test="$counter.isLast">
                        <div class="hoverover">
                            <ss:image source="$storeVersion.images['hoverOver.gif']"/>
                        </div>  
                    </ss:if>
                </ss:if>
            </ss:if>
        </ss:foreach>
    <ss:else/>
        <div class="notavailable">
            <div style="padding:50px">Photo Not Available</div>
        </div>
    </ss:if>
</td>
```

CSS portion of code:

```
/****** MULTIPLE IMAGES ****** product detail page */
.click {cursor:pointer}
.imagesmallcontainer {
    background-color:#ffffff;
border:2px solid #CCCCCC;
display:inline-block;
height:65px;
margin:4px 4px 2px 0px;
overflow:hidden;
width:65px;
    position: relative;
}
.hoverover {
display:inline-block;
font-size:11px;
padding-bottom:2px;
padding-top:2px;
    position: relative;
}
.notavailable {
background-color:#ffffff;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
color:#666666;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Since I'm using a template from a webhost, I'm not sure if anyone can help...but I thought it would be worth a shot.

Thanks in advance,
Marcy

Answer (score 0):

Use `Float:left` either for **.imagesmallcontainer** element or for **img** tag inside it. And it'll work.